# team foundation server connection string

Tags: asp.net, tfs, connection-string

I am using Team foundation server and I have a problem with the Database. What connection string should I use? I have my connection string on my computer but it's different for every computer.

Comment: What do you mean, "it's different for every computer?" My guess is that your problem is that you have a single connection string in a .config file in TFS, but each developer needs a different connection string that points to their own DB. Is that correct? (That is, the connection string itself is nothing to do with TFS.)

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. So everyone who uses the TFS should have a config file with says his connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem in a number of ways. I'm assuming here that your connection string is currently in a standard `app.config` or `web.config` file. Also, this list is almost certainly not exhaustive...

- The simplest (but ugliest) is for each user to check out the config file and put their own connection string in locally. This works, but you will get unnecessary changes checked in to the config file.
- If your developers are all using local instances of SQL and the database name is the same on each machine, you can simply use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your connection string to point at the local machine. This will work on all machines as long as the database name is consistent.
- You can move the connection string *out* of the config file, into a separate file or location that is not checked into TFS. For example, you could check for a `userOverrides.config` file (that you never check in), or pull the connection string from the registry instead. You could still use the core configuration file to provide a default value, but nobody would need to edit it for day-to-day work.

Comment: Can you give me example how to use your second way of solving this problem? My team foundation server and the DB are in visualstudio.com hosting.

Comment: The second example will only work if the database is hosted on each developer's own machine - `localhost` points to the machine you're on, so if the connection string uses `localhost` then each developer will connect to their own machine.